# Nginx proxy_pass without trailing slash needed

Tags: docker, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I am trying to get my nginx reverse proxy to pass to 1 of 2 apache webservers. But there is a problem with my setup. When I want to connect to 'localhost/central/api' it only works if I go to 'localhost/central/api/' (the trailing slash).
Otherwise the url is changed to 'localhost/central/' again.

It seems weird that this is needed/wanted, I don't know how to fix this.
It does not seem to be caused by the apache apps.
I don't want the last trailing slash to be needed and I also don't want nginx to add this to the end of the url when passing to my apache services.

This is the relevant part of my config file for nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location ^~ /central {
        proxy_pass http://central/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location ^~ /microservices {
        proxy_pass http://microservices/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```

Have tried using rewrite rules instead but this also didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you try using curl to see if you get a redirect response back by doing `curl -v http://localhost/central/api`?

Comment: Yes, i do see a redirect when i use curl.

Comment: There's nothing in your nginx config that should cause a redirect, so it's probably coming from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure no URI to the `proxy_pass` directive, NGINX will simply pass the same URI as the requested to the proxied service.

Reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

So basically remove the trailing slash. Also, I would add a trailing slash to the location, otherwise things like `/central-park/api` will also match:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location ^~ /central/ {
        proxy_pass http://central;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location ^~ /microservices/ {
        proxy_pass http://microservices;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I should expect apache to send this redirect, but my browser was not handling it properly because it was doing some sort of internal caching.

Also the redirects did not have the 'central' or 'microservices' subpath.
The redirect would give a uri of localhost/api.

I fixed this using a proxy redirect rule:

```
 proxy_redirect http://central http://localhost/central;
```